# Setting Variable based on Return Value from Function - Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, fs

Good evening,

Forgive me if there is an obvious solution, I'm a bit new to JavaScript.

I'm attempting to update my Discord bot to read a line of text from a txt file, and send the line as a message. I've gotten everything working, except I'm getting undefined when I try to send my variable that is supposed to be holding the text from the txt file.

I have a function that reads from the text file. I've written the result to a log and it seems to be reading everything properly:

```
function readQOTDText(file){
     var result

     fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => { 
         if (err) throw err
         result = data.toString()
     }) 

     return result
}
```

...and here is the function for sending the message:

```
function sendMessage(){
   const guildID = client.guilds.cache.get("my guild ID here")

   if(guildID && guildID.channels.cache.get('my channel ID here')){
      guildID.channels.cache.get('my channel ID here').send(readQOTDText('qotd.txt'))
   }
}
```

I've tried probably 10 different ways for it to successfully send the string pulled from the txt file, but it's always undefined. I've tried setting the result to a variable and I get the same result.

I'm thinking it has something to do with how JS functions run (I believe it's called AJAX?), but I'm very new to JS and nothing I've found online has helped.

Thank you for any insight anyone can provide.

Comment: `fs.readFile()` is asynchronous.

Comment: Use `fs.readFileSync()`

Comment: @Barmar, I tried switching to that and I'm still getting "Cannot send an empty message". Possible it could be something else?

Comment: What do you see if you put `console.log(result)` inside the callback function?

Comment: Using readFileSync, I don't get anything, but using readFile, it prints the text from the txt file. @Barmar

Comment: I assumed you were doing this in node.js, and updated tags accordingly. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thank you for the updates! @Barmar

Comment: @Barmar, turns out the way I was trying to read the file was only storing the contents INSIDE the fs.readFile() function. I changed it to a new method and it's successfully sending the variable message. Thanks for all your help!